# Defining global variables in php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, SQL Server 2008 R2, php 5.2.6
I'm new to PHP. I have this file called globalvars.php where global variables are defined.

**globalvars.php**

```
<?
  session_start();
  include_once('database.php');

  //global vars
  $_APP["SQL_DB_NAME"]="DB_NAME";
  $_APP["SQL_DB_SERVER_NAME"]="SERVER_NAME";
  $_APP["SQL_DB_USER"]="USERNAME";
  $_APP["SQL_DB_PASS"]="PASSWORD";

  $_APP["DATE_FORMAT"] = "d-m-Y";
  $_APP["TIME_FORMAT"] = "H:i";

  //generic function for SQL composition to avoid 's errors     
  function SQuoteEx($str)
  {
return "'" . str_replace("'","''",$str) . "'";
  }
  function RemoveSQuoteEx($str)
  {
return "'" . str_replace("'","",$str) . "'";
  }
  ?>
```

and i also have this file called database.php where the global vars are called with a snippet function that connects to the SQL Server database:

**database.php**

```
function DBConnect($sql,$debug=0)
  {
global $_APP;
//connect to db and execute query
$cnn = mssql_connect($_APP["SQL_DB_SERVER_NAME"], $_APP["SQL_DB_USER"],       $_APP["SQL_DB_PASS"]) or die(errorHandlingPage(mssql_get_last_message()));
$selected = mssql_select_db($_APP["SQL_DB_NAME"], $cnn) or die(errorHandlingPage(mssql_get_last_message())); 
$debug = 0;
//if debug mode echo sql
if ($debug) echo $sql."<br>";
//execute and return rs

$return = mssql_query($sql) or die(errorHandlingPage(mssql_get_last_message()));

if($return){
    return $return;
}   
  }
```

for some reason the global vars cannot be read by the database.php file. Any ideas what's going on? No message by mssql_get_last_message() was passed. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you actually calling your `DBConnect` function?

Comment: at the bottom of the database.php file, there are other functions where I use the DBConnect function.

Comment: So @cegfault is correct...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are including the `database.php` file *before* you are declaring the global variables.  Just move `include_once('database.php');` to the bottom of the declarations.

In PHP, when you `include` another PHP file, that file is parsed and executed *immediately*.  You should declare any variables you need *before* making the `include_once('database.php');` file.

Comment: i put the include_once('database.php'); code to the bottom of the declarations, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Which page are u calling in the browser? It looks like u will call database.php file in the browser to run the function.

Having said that, in database.php file, you should include globalvars.php on the beginning of the file.

**database.php**

```
include_once('globalvars.php');
// rest of your code...
```